# windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" и ScrollView

Tags: android, scrollview

Всем привет, подскажите от куда может браться padding (а может margin) в ScrollView?

https://monosnap.com/file/ONg7yrobI7cMJjLw4ixmWaELEmP2bA

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/root_view"
    android:background="#fff">

<ScrollView
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/scrollview"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="#12950d">
...
```

Тема:

```
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarSize">55dp</item>

        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>

        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:icon">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar styles -->
    <style name="ActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: окажите свой XML леяута

Comment: Там все стандартно, пробовал добавить android:fitsSystemWindows="true" толку нет.

Comment: пробовали на реальном устройстве? Странно очень, если все стандартно... Может тема не стандартная?

Comment: Думал из-за android:windowActionBarOverlay уберал - толку нет.

Comment: попробуйте новый леяут, и в него положить`ScollView`. Поэкспериментируйте

Comment: А у самих вьюх то маргинов нет никаких?

Comment: Пробовал убрать все, не помогло, но размер отсупа изменился

Comment: Нашел причину android:layout_gravity="center"

Answer (score 1):

Пересчет высоты (padding-ов) был не верен из-за:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/root_view"
        android:background="#fff">

        <ScrollView
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/scrollview"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:background="#12950d">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center" <-------!!!!!!!!!
                android:background="#a4deca">
```